# how to redirect JQuery URL with variable and array value

Tags: jquery

I have below code where i am redirecting URL with JQuery but now i need to also send variable and array with the redirection name and id values. how can i achieve this ?

```
<html> 
<head> 
    <title>redirect to another page</title>
 </head>
  <body>
     
     
     <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.6.2.min.js"></script>
      <script> 
      var name = "Sam";
      var id = 5;
      $(document).ready(function() {
        var url = "microsoft-edge:http://test-dev/test.jsp"; 
        $(location).attr('href',url); }); 
    </script> 
    </body>
```

Comment: i need to send name and id to the redirection url page,

Comment: Use URL [`searchParams`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/URL/searchParams)